# Rails 4 error: ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update, param not found: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I have a users controller with standard CRUD methods. One of the methods is Update.

```
def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user, notice: "Account Successfully updated"
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Then I have the rails 4 strong params method:

```
private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids => [])
end
```

My view is like so:

```
<% if is_admin?(current_user) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[role_ids][]", nil %>
    <% Role.all.each do |role|%>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include?(role.id) %>
    <%= role.name %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end%>
</br></br>

<footer>
<nav>
<%= link_to "Update User", user_path(@user), :method => :put%>
</nav>
</footer>
```

When I click the update User link in the view. I get this error:

```
 ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update
 param not found: user
```

The highlighted line for the error is:

```
  private
  def user_params
```

> ```
>  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
>  :password_confirmation, :role_ids => [])
>         end
> ```

I cannot seem to explain why Im getting this error since the strong params condition is satisfied.

Any ideas?

---

Request params:

```
Started PUT "/users/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-18 16:33:58 -0400
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"1JONmLnMcf2A/2y9boXmcPG5UiwahyR0loLfw+lshco=", "id"=>"4"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: user):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:49:in `user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

Comment: Paste your request params.

Comment: As you can see in the params, you are sending just the "id" for the user, you need to send the params for the create(user_params) otherwise it won't work. As Stated in my answer, use form helpers.

Comment: Update the post with the next problems you find to adapt my answer to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are not nesting the params inside "user" key.

The .require(:user) is looking for a hash like this:

```
{"user"=>{params}}
```

The form is not correct, you have to add the user key before sending it.

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
  #form items.

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

You can redefine the params for this action to:

```
private
def user_params
    params.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids => [])
end
```

Comment: Im confused. Which form? There is no form in my question.

Comment: Either you use a form helper for this action to avoid this problem, or use the edit solution.

Comment: I had this same issue as well and just needed to send the params has as your answer denotes. Thanks a lot.